# return in a jTable the results of Search without SQL (with DAOMock)

Tags: java, swing, search, jtable, action-interface

I have this action `ActionFindPeople` and I want to search in a db a people by name and surname inserted in 2 different text fields.

```
public class ActionFindPeople extends AbstractAction{

    private Control control;

    public ActionFindPeople (Control control) {
        this.control = control;
        this.putValue(Action.NAME, "FIND");
        this.putValue(Action.SHORT_DESCRIPTION, "Find People");
        this.putValue(Action.MNEMONIC_KEY, new Integer(KeyEvent.VK_F));
        this.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("CTRL F"));
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Vist vist = (Vist) this.control.getVist();
        PanelInitial pi = (PanelInitial ) vist.getUnderVist(Costant.PANEL_INITIAL);
        PannelResult pr = (PannelResult) vist.getUnderVist(Costant.PANEL_RESULT);
        Model model = (Model) this.control.getModel();

        String name = pi.getTextFieldName().getText();
        String surname = pi.getTextFieldSurname().getText();

        Db db=  (Db) control.getModel().getBean(Costant.DB);

        Person personToFind = findPerson(name, surname, db);
        if(personToFind != null) {
            model.putBean(Costant.PERSON_FOUND, personToFind );
            prp.changeComponent((Person) this.control.getModel().getBean(Costant.PERSON_FOUND));
            vist.changePanel();
        } else {
            vist.windowError("Insesistent people for " + name+ " " + surname);
        }
    }

    public Person findPerson(String name, String surname, Db db) {
        List<Person> listPerson = db.getListPerson();
        for (Person p : listPerson){
            if(p.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name) && p.getSurname().equalsIgnoreCase(surname)){
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I want try to put the people that have name and surname equals in a jTable, but when i ll do it, if people exists it turn me back all the people in the DataBase! How can i solve this problem??? Here is it also the code for refresh the Model of Table.

```
public void refreshModel() {

    Model model = (Model) this.vist.getModel();
    Person person = (Person) model.getBean(Costanti.PERSON);
    Db a = (Db) model.getBean(Costanti.DB);

    ModelTable mt = new ModelTable (a);
    this.jTable.setModel(mt);
    this.jTable.setSelectionMode(SINGLE_SELECTION);
    this.jScrollPane1.setViewportView(this.jTable);

}
```

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your question/problem, but you may want to look at [table sorting and filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). You can use the a regex filter with firstname|surname. If this is a problem with db querying, maybe you should show you db access code. If this is just a matter of the table not updating with new data, I don't think the code you've provided gives enough detail, as you have many references to custom classes we cannot see, along with not being able to see any component interaction flow

Comment: the database is a DAOmock... can u help me?